# View File Uploads in Custom Module Admin Screen

Tags: files, 9

I'd like to show a list of the files in a directory in my default/files directory. This will show's all files:

```
/**
 * Helper function to retrieve and display a list of current uploads.
 */
protected function getCurrentUploadsList() {
  $uploads = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('file')
    ->loadByProperties(['status' => FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT]);

  $output = '<h2>Current Uploads</h2>';
  $output .= '<ul>';
  foreach ($uploads as $file) {
    $output .= '<li>' . $file->getFilename() . '</li>';
  }
  $output .= '</ul>';

  return $output;
}
```

This is my attempt at showing only for a certain directory:

```
protected function getCurrentUploadsList()
  {
    $folder_uri = 'public://idv-uploads/';
    $uploads = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('file')->loadByProperties(['uri' => $folder_uri]);
    $output = '<h2>Current Uploads in idv-uploads Folder</h2>';
    $output .= '<ul>';
    foreach ($uploads as $file) {
      $output .= '<li>' . $file->getFilename() . '</li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
    return $output;
  }
```

What am I missing in the loadByProperties? Thanks!

Comment: The URI of every file would have to equal `$folder_uri` for that code to work. That is why you get no results.